# PHPのemptyでバックスラッシュを付けてはいけない理由

Tags: php

PHPは7.0です。
`empty()`に他の`\json_decode()`などと同じようにバックスラッシュ`\`を付けて使おうとすると
(個人的にわかりやすいように今の名前空間より上にたどるものには関数も`\`を付けるようにしています)

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'empty' (T_EMPTY), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in パス`

と言われます。

付けなかったら動くのですがこれはつまりPHPのグローバル名前空間?に定義された関数ではなく演算子のようなものということでしょうか?

もし他にもこのようなものの例がありましたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: [PHP: List of Keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) を見ますと、`empty()` は PHP のキーワードになっていますね。`Some of them represent things which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but they're not, really: they are language constructs.`

Comment: @metropolis なるほどキーワードというのですね。文法上おかしいというようなエラーだったのも納得です。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

metropolisさんが書かれているように、`empty()` はPHPのキーワードです。
この関数に見える `empty()` は、言語構造のため、通常の関数としての処理ではなく、解釈、実行されます。トークン一覧に存在する、例えば isset() なども同様かと思います。

- http://php.net/manual/ja/tokens.php