# PHPでclassを定義しようとするとエラーが出ます

Tags: php

ごく単純な記述です。
phpの記述の下にはHTML内でインスタンスを作成したり、メソッドの実行などを記述していましたが消しました。
添付画像のように"on line 2"、すなわち2行目の"class List{"の部分です。

何度か見直したり書き直ししたのですが、 エラーが消えません。
エディタはVSCode、ブラウザはChromeで環境はXAMPPです。

理由のわかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。
宜しくお願い致します。

```
<?php
class List{
    public $name;
    public $age;
    
    public function hello(){
        echo "こんにちは";
    }
}
?>
```

**エラー内容**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'List' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs●●●●.php on line 2
```

Comment: 参考:[PHPのemptyでバックスラッシュを付けてはいけない理由](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35858/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List`がキーワード(予約語)だからでしょう。

[キーワードのリスト](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/reserved.keywords.php)

> これらのキーワードは、PHP では特別な意味があります。これらのいくつかは 関数やメソッドのようなものを表し、いくつかは定数のようなものを表す、 といったようになっていますが、実際にはそうではありません。実際には、 これらは言語を構成するものです。以下のキーワードはいずれも定数、クラス名、 関数名として使用することはできません。 これらを変数名として使用することは一般的には可能ですが、 混乱を生じる可能性があります。

[Are PHP keywords case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20624257/9014308)

> Case insensitive (both user defined and PHP defined)
>
> - functions
> - class constructors
> - class methods
> - keywords and constructs (if, else, null, foreach, echo etc.)

関数やクラスコンストラクタ/メソッドは大文字小文字の区別が無いので、[list()](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.list.php)と衝突したということでしょう。

他にもあります。
[予約語の一覧](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/reserved.php)